# Первая выборка с бд

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы данный код делал все выборки с бд, а не только последнию добавленную запись?

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
    printf ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(function(){ 
$('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' + 
($('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('" .$row['name'] . "') != -1 ? '".$row['email'] ."' : '+77777777')); 
});
</script>"
    );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
         ?>
```

Comment: Самое странно, что если вставить несколько одинаковый скриптов, то ни один не работает

Comment: А если вставлять без запроса напрямую в html все работает

Comment: Обратите внимание что вы используете неподдерживаемые функции mysql_* объявленные как deprecated несколько лет назад. Используйте mysqli или PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как насчёт

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $(function(){ 
            $('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' +     ($('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('" .$row['name'] . "') != -1 ? '".$row['email'] ."' : '+77777777')); 
        });
        </script>"; 
}
```

?